# Set "App & Browser Control" in Windows Security to be on by default for all Users

Tags: windows, group-policy

In the Security settings page for Windows 10/11, there's an App & Browser control option that is off by default:

[image: App & Browser Control capture from Windows Settings]

This further causes the task bar icon to show a warning:

[image: Taskbar Security Warning in Windows 11]

I'd like my users trained for this warning to be a Big Deal™ they should either correct or report to IT for assistance, and therefore also that App & Browser control should be turned on by default.

Unfortunately, I cannot find how to turn this on for all users by default. Obviously one user is *easy*, but from what I've seen this setting is per user profile, rather than machine wide. This is further backed up by the fact that my research so far sometimes points to the HKEY_CURRENT user hive for a registry fix...

...which would be okay. I could push out that fix via Group Policy. But none of the fixes I've seen seem to actually work. The feature continues to show it's turned off, and taskbar warning icon remains visible.

There is a Group Policy option to hide this section completely, but then it remains off. I'd like it turned on. We do not have Intune or other MDM available for these PCs.

We only use the built-in Microsoft Defender antivirus.

How can I fix this?

---

Some things I've tried that did NOT work:

Registry:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Polices\Microsoft\Windows Defender\PUAProtection to 1
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Edge\SmartScreenPuaEnabled to 1
```

Group Policy:

```
Computer\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft Defender Antivirus\Configure Detection for unwanted applications

Computer\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Defender SmartScreen\Explorer\Configure W... \
(Warn and Block)

User\Policies\Administrative Templates\Microsoft Edge\SmartScreen  
(Enabled and Block potentially unwanted apps)
```

Comment: Which fixes have you seen/tried? So that people won't repeat them as potential solutions

Comment: Too many, but I'll add a few I know I've checked to the question.

Comment: which settings under "App & browser control" are showing as disabled? If it's just the "Reputation-based protection" (smartscreen), then open the settings and check which specific parts of it are still disabled for you. There are four, and they're set in different parts of group policy

Comment: @Cpt.Whale That was what I needed. I was looking for one setting. Applying EVERYTHING seems to do the job.